# How to read filenames from a folder using xslt?

Tags: xslt

I have to read filenames from 2 folders say e.g. dir1 and dir2 which have files with same names. 
dir1 contains a.xml, b.xml, c.xml
dir2 contains a.xml,b.xml,c.xml
now I need to pass e.g dir1/a.xml,dir2/a.xml  as parameters to another xsl script which compares some nodes in these 2 files

there are around 100 files in these 2 folders.

as of now I am using Oxygen editor.

Can you please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Saxon 9 in Oxygen and XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 then you can use `collection('dir1?select=*.xml')` to pull in all files `*.xml` files from `dir1` into your stylesheet (you will have a sequence of document nodes returned from that `collection()` call). If you want to use an absolute path to a directory make sure you use a file URI in the form of e.g. `collection('file:///C:/SomeDir/SomeSubDir/dir1?select=*.xml')`. See the section "Processing directories" in http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html for more details.